# Fasterxml Jackson DateTimeSerializer makes no suitable HttpMessageConverter

Tags: android, jackson

I have json like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Rudi Wijaya",
        "photoId": "rudi_wijaya_facebook_1763547129_fb_8673568292060043679",
        "id": "rudi",
        "creationTime": 1495187730806,
        "modificationTime": 1497599396889,
        "description": null,
       :
       :
    },
    "message": null,
    "httpStatus": "OK"
}
```

And I call it from rest-template spring android:

```
restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());    
final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);    
requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();    
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

final UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(context.getString(R.string.api_log_in));
uriBuilder.queryParam("username",upPerson.getId());
uriBuilder.queryParam("password",upPerson.getPassword());
final URI uri = uriBuilder.build().toUri();
final HttpEntity<Void> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);

final ResponseEntity<CatalogResponse<Person>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
        uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<CatalogResponse<Person>>() {});
final CatalogResponse<Person> result = responseEntity.getBody();
final Person loggedInPerson = result.getData();
```

Pojo:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private String photoId;

    private String id;

    @JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private DateTime creationTime;

    @JsonSerialize(using= DateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private DateTime modificationTime;

    private String slug;    

    @JsonSerialize(using= LocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using=LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate birthDate;


    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    :
    (set and getter)
    :

}

public class CatalogResponse<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Nullable
    private T data;
    private String message;
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    private Exception e;

    public CatalogResponse() {
        super();
    }

    :
    (set and getter)
    :

}
```

And I got error:

```
Failed to sign-in use username or email'rudi': org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [id.co.bippo.tlc.controller.CatalogResponse<id.co.bippo.tlc.controller.entities.Person>] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [id.co.bippo.tlc.controller.CatalogResponse<id.co.bippo.tlc.controller.entities.Person>] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:723)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:544)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:512)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:490)
```

in environment:

```
compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.9'

compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'

 compile (
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.9'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.8.9'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.9']
    )
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-joda', version: '2.8.9'

<jackson.version>2.8.9</jackson.version>
<joda-time.version>2.9.9</joda-time.version>
```

If I removed all:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
```

the error message is gone...

Comment: @Abhi thanks for editing the json.. I could not formatted it, because i got "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Answer (score 0):

The deserializer specified in `@JsonDeserialize` must have a no-args constructor for Jackson to be able to use it. As you can see in the [DateTimeDeserializer docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-joda/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/deser/DateTimeDeserializer.html) it doesn't have a no args constructor.

The intended way to use it is without a `@JsonDeserialize` annotation. As long as you register `JodaModule` (which you do) it will internally use `DateTimeDeserializer` whenever it has to deserialize into a `DateTime`